# open specific installed application (in PC) from my web page

Tags: angular, desktop-application

I am working on angular 4 application and in one scenario i need to open specific installed application in PC.

Opened application should run standalone.

Is there any way to open application from my web page ?

Comment: you have to apply some settings in registry

Comment: Is there a way to start an application installed in windows(eg. notepad, vlc etc) from a link click in a website? Updating registry may not be a solution as all the website users will not be able to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes we can open windows application from web page as below.

**1)** Open Registry Editor by typing `regedit` in run command(window+R).

**2)** Goto `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

**3)** Find application that you want to open from browser.

**4)** For example i am targeting to microsoft word so make sure it hase key 
like Url:Word Protocol as mentioned in below screenshot.
[image]

**5)** Also check command key has value as displayed in below screenshot.

[image]

**6)** Now in webpage you just need to put `<a href="Word:">Let's Open Word</a>`

That's All.